# Count the occurences of multiple items in an array

Tags: json, mongodb, database

I have a document like this

```
{
"text": "test description",
"tags": ["house", "garden", "wall"]
}
```

Now if I want to match multiply tags in MongoDB I do

```
db.test.find( { tags: { $in: [ "house", "garden", "fish" ] } } );
```

Is there a method to get the amount of matching tags for each document (like in the text search with  $meta: "textScore")
so that i can sort how exactly the document matches my query in descending order?

For my example above I would like to know that there are 2 matching tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) I think.

Something like this

```
db.test.aggregate( {$unwind:'$tags'},
                   {$match: {tags:{$in: ["house", "garden", "fish"]}}},
                   {$group: {_id:'$_id', tagcount:{$sum: 1}}} )
```

Explanation:

- [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) part makes a document for each element in the tags array
- [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) selects from those documents those matching the tags in the list
- [$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) greates a document grouped by _id and counts each matching document

Result should be a list of documents of the form

```
{_id: id, tagcount: #matching tags}
```

You can also add a [sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) at the end like

```
{$sort:{tagcount : -1}}
```

So a aggregate query on your structure to return the _id, text, matching tags and number of matching tags sorted in descending order by the number of matching tags:

```
db.test.aggregate( {$unwind:'$tags'},
                   {$match: {tags:{$in: ["house", "garden", "fish"]}}},
                   {$group: {_id: '$_id' , text : {$first:'$text'},
                             tags:{$addToSet:'$tags'}, tagcount:{$sum: 1}}},
                   {$sort:{tagcount:-1}})
```

result for your example document

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5..."), 
  "text" : "test description", 
  "tags" : [ "garden", "house" ],
  "tagcount" : 2 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
In the first example is a small typo colon is missing after $in.